# What are the legal considerations to build a service like Drupal Gardens and earn profit from it?

Tags: 7

I ask for your help to clarify a doubt I had on the usage and licensing of the Drupal platform to build a commercial project like [Drupal Gardens](https://www.drupalgardens.com).

Today, I have read both licensing and usage rules from the drupal.com and drupal.org, but I have found nothing that could give an straight answer to my curiosity about what will take both legally and economic to maintain a site 'like' Drupal Gardens. Being specific a service where people will pay to get a deployed Drupal instance.

Comment: I don't think that your question can be answered by anyone other than a lawyer.

Comment: In addition to tim.plunkett: This question does not belong here, IMO, because it has little to do with Drupal specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary complication is the use of the Trademark "Drupal" in the product or service's name or domain. You'll need to contact the Drupal Association at http://association.drupal.org, or Dries Buytaert, the trademark holder.

If you're not interested in using the Drupal trademark as part of your product or service's name there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: thanks for reply, as my understanding it shouldn't be any problem as long as I don't use the trademark at all?

Comment: I don't think so, there is buzzr http://www.buzzr.com/ which is in the same space as drupalgardens

Comment: @Dipen thanks for mention the site, they are indeed in a similar line of business that drupalgardens... so it is possible to build something alike.

Answer (score 1):

Since you will be using the drupal code ( GPL ) in SaaS model of deploying drupal sites for your customers there would be no legal issues. Like eaton said, trademark violation could be an issue you can read drupal trademark policy here - http://drupal.com/trademark